# Hybrid app background image jumps on screen instead of loading first

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, background-image

I am working on a hybrid HTML5, Jquery Mobile application using phonegap. I am currently having an issue with a background image I set using CSS. I have a CSS class (bPage) that sets the background image and color and all that and it seems to work right. The issue is when you navigate to a page that requires scrolling. Because the image is set to be in the center it moves to the center of the page, which is great. The problem is that the page loads with the image in the spot of the previous page and then it jumps to the middle. I want to make it move the image before the rest of the page loads so that it doens't look like the background jumps last in the page loading. Both pages have the class bPage on them and it is working correctly, except for the jumping. I assume that there is a way to force this to load earlier or something but have not been able to find a way.

Here is my bPage CSS code:

```
.bPage{
    background-color: #6c6d6f;
    background-image: url(../img/Backgrounds/Background.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you're applying that class to a `<div data-role="page">` right? have you tried forcing the height of the page to 100%?

Comment: Have a look here, maybe some extra css settings might help  -- http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Yes, I am applying the 'data-role="page' and I tried forcing the page to 100% but that didn't help. 
Interesting link, but it didn't seem to be exactly what I am looking for.
Just to clarify, The finalized position of the image is correct. I am just trying to get rid of the delay of it jumping to that position so the user doesn't feel the delay.